# File not found Exception while copying Android File

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am trying to use this code.

```
public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode,
        final Intent data) {
     String filePath = null;
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
         switch (requestCode) {
         case RESULT_MEMORY_SAVE:               
             filePath = data.getDataString();
             copyFileForReceipts(filePath,pathOfReceipts);
```

Now filePath is a String , Debugger shows its value as `"content://media/external/images/media/133"`

Next i am trying to use this:

```
sourceLocation  = filePath;
File afile = new File(sourceLocation); 
File bfile = new File(targetLocation + "file.jpg");
inStream = new FileInputStream(afile.getName()); //Gives exception
outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile.getName());
```

Its gives an exception of `FileNotFound` exception. I have tried removing `.getName()` too.

Please tell me where am i wrong.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using *setData* and *getDataString*, you should put the file path and retrieve it as follow:

to add path in result producing activity:

```
intent.putString("path", file_path);
```

and to retrieve path:

```
filePath = data.getString("path");
copyFileForReceipts(filePath,pathOfReceipts);
```

and its a good practice to check the existence of file before doing anything further on it:

```
if(afile.exists()){
   //do whatever you want
}
```